# Quick regex help: grab text from html

Tags: regex

I have the following html snippet:

```
<h1 class="header" itemprop="name">Some text here<span class="nobr">
```

I would like to get the text between the html tags, I'm struggling with this for hours now, please help me! What regex would solve my problem?

Comment: Regular expressions should not be used for HTML parsing. Use a parser.

Comment: [In general it cannot be done.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) But you could try `<[^>]*>([^<]*)<.*>`

Answer (score 0):

You should not use regex for that, but some HTML parser. As you didn't specify language, it is hard to help, but you will find it by googling...

---

If you need it just for this one case, you can use regex `/>(.*?)</`

Comment: Ok - I was using the C# engine where it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can access that info via:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("h1").item(0).textContent
```

or

```
document.getElementsByClassName("header").item(0).textContent
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other's have said - **you shouldn't be using regular expressions for parsing HTML**.  But with that aside the following will grab that text for you:

`(?<=\>).+(?=\<)`